# How can I fix this Map Activity error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Well,I'm quite new to Android Studio. When I learned to create an easy app,which is so basic, showing the map at Sydney,Austria. It didn't work though I followed all the way from the tutorial.

It showed error of "transform classes with dex for debug" and then I googled and fixed it by using  and there was no error anymore.

However,on the emulator, it showed that my application has stopped running.
How can I fix this?

This is the error message I got

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4563)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
>                         at

How can I fix this? It's just basic google map app,which I think I followed all the steps.

Comment: Can you provide some code and a stack trace?

Comment: I don't have thing to show.It just what you learned from the first time you learned to use Google Map Activity like get API key and the put it on the code and then press Run button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps to create Map Activity [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)
then set **multiDexEnabled** to **true** in your **Build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.my.app"
      multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: I did that already.It showed no error anymore.However,on emulator,it showed "Unfortunately,My Application has stopped running".

Comment: if you are using Android Studio try to debug your app (don't run it )  shift+f9 to debug ... if you got the error in android monitor add it to your question to see whats the problem

Comment: Add the applicationId to the application's build.gradle like the edited answer